# Can I share MessageGroupID between several queues on AWS SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, fifo

I have 3 AWS SQS FIFO for scalability. Each one of them triggers a complex task that I'm going to call `create`, `createWithPriority` and `update` just for simplicity.

I need a transversal `MessageGroupID` (I think this is the way, but I'm open to suggestions here) so I can **get the messages in order from the three queues**, given that I can't make an update over something that wasn't created yet.

I've seen [some articles about complex SQS management](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/solving-complex-ordering-challenges-with-amazon-sqs-fifo-queues/), but I couldn't find anyone about `MessageGroupID` sharing...or something to achieve the **check by group** that I need.

I'm trying to use (if exists) an AWS way to do it. I'll think that there is a good practice that I'm missing here.

Otherwise, I'll have a consumer lambda workaround, but I have to try.

Comment: Make sure you need separate queues, because SQS is scalability out of box and if you the limits you reach are soft, so contacting AWS support will help to solve the scalability issue. 
Additionally, check the guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-throughput-horizontal-scaling-and-batching.html
It may also help for 3 queues just not to delete messages from `update` topic if an object isn't created yet. This will set a visibility timeout that will help to solve the issue. Also, in this case you probably don't need FIFO queues.

Comment: Hi, Yann, thanks for your answer! Our scalability is functional, not a performance thing, so we can't use only one queue. I understand what you mean, and if that was the case, you are totally right, but they have 3 different priorities and functionally that we can't mix in one.

Comment: About the visibility, I'm going to try that. Seems useful. Actually my workaround was check, with the consumer lambda for the update, if the create has been done and reentry if not. But your visibility suggestion is a good one!